# How we can fetch variable value from gitlab to value.yaml in helm chart

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

We have database password which we want to store in Gitlab Variable rather in secret.yaml file in helm chart. So how can I fetch the variable here in value.yaml file so that I can pass it to deployment.yaml file ?

Currently we are passing the id and password in the secret file . But we want to fetch the id and password from Gitlab variable.